# Clustering words together by looking at vector similiarity (Python)

Tags: python, list, scikit-learn, nlp, cluster-analysis

I have a long list with the format

```
mylist =[([256, 408, 147, 628], 'ezis'), ([628, 526, 236, 676], 'camera'), ([526, 876, 676, 541], 'camera'), ([567, 731, 724, 203], 'size'), ([822, 187, 256, 172], 'camera'), ([489, 628, 214, 428], 'esu'), ([648, 487, 487, 338], 'take'), ([487, 606, 338, 428], 'pictur'),.....]

#The full list can be found at https://pastebin.com/Mn9En3r6
```

Where the vectors paired with each word in this represent the unique index of words surrounding it in a sentence (i.e the number 256 represents 'big' etc.)

In this long list there is only 100 unique words, 50 real words and 50 words which are just those real words reversed (size -> ezis)

I want to cluster them together by comparing their vector values and hopefully, most of the real words and their reversed counterpart should be paired.

I'd ideally like to use the Sklearn clustering library (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.AgglomerativeClustering.html) but the problem I'm having is I'm not too sure how to implement this.

Would taking the 'average vector' value of each of these 100 words and then clustering them together work? If so, how would I do this?

Comment: In my opinion, taking the `average vector` on indices that you probably assigned randomly is not the best way. By randomly I mean there is no relation between the difference of the words their-selves and their meaning and context. I mean you might assign 101 and 102 to the words `water` and `moon` which are far away from each other or assign 151 and 152 to the words `dog` and `husky` which are close in meaning and the context.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this?

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import AffinityPropagation
import distance
    
words = '''[([256, 408, 147, 628], 'ezis'), ([628, 526, 236, 676], 'camera'), ([526, 876, 676, 541], 'camera'), ([567, 731, 724, 203], 'size'), ([822, 187, 256, 172], 'camera'), ([489, 628, 214, 428], 'esu'), ([648, 487, 487, 338], 'take'), ([487, 606, 338, 428], 'pictur')'''.split(',') #Replace this line
words = np.asarray(words) #So that indexing with a list will work
lev_similarity = -1*np.array([[distance.levenshtein(w1,w2) for w1 in words] for w2 in words])

affprop = AffinityPropagation(affinity="precomputed", damping=0.5)
affprop.fit(lev_similarity)
for cluster_id in np.unique(affprop.labels_):
    exemplar = words[affprop.cluster_centers_indices_[cluster_id]]
    cluster = np.unique(words[np.nonzero(affprop.labels_==cluster_id)])
    cluster_str = ", ".join(cluster)
    print(" - *%s:* %s" % (exemplar, cluster_str))
```

You could do this too.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.metrics import adjusted_rand_score

documents = ["([256, 408, 147, 628], 'ezis')",
             "([628, 526, 236, 676], 'camera')",
             "([526, 876, 676, 541], 'camera')",
             "([567, 731, 724, 203], 'size')",
             "([822, 187, 256, 172], 'camera')",
             "([489, 628, 214, 428], 'esu')",
             "([648, 487, 487, 338], 'take')"]

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english')
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(documents)

true_k = 8
model = KMeans(n_clusters=true_k, init='k-means++', max_iter=1000, n_init=1)
model.fit(X)

print("Top terms per cluster:")
order_centroids = model.cluster_centers_.argsort()[:, ::-1]
terms = vectorizer.get_feature_names()
for i in range(true_k):
    print("Cluster %d:" % i),
    for ind in order_centroids[i, :10]:
        print(' %s' % terms[ind]),
    print

print("\n")
print("Prediction")

Y = vectorizer.transform(["chrome browser to open."])
prediction = model.predict(Y)
print(prediction)

Y = vectorizer.transform(["My cat is hungry."])
prediction = model.predict(Y)
print(prediction)
```